# Concurrent insertion to oracle

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

I have asp.net application with oracle database, in my application I insert many records to table in oracle with one hit, every row will have ID generated by the system with specific roles, and I want this ID to be as a series for all inserted records with the same hit. my issue happened when two users click on insert at the same time the ID the ID is not in a series. I want a way from oracle or .net to complete the first hit and then start the another with sequence.

Examples with ID
User 1 
XX-YY-ZZ-1
XX-YY-ZZ-2
XX-YY-ZZ-3

User 2
XX-YY-ZZ-3
XX-YY-ZZ-5
XX-YY-ZZ-6

What happened is

User 1
XX-YY-ZZ-1
XX-YY-ZZ-4
XX-YY-ZZ-6

User 2
XX-YY-ZZ-2
XX-YY-ZZ-3
XX-YY-ZZ-5

Comment: Are you saying that for each user, their inserts should occur in sequence? I.e. user1 xx1 xx2 xx3, user 2 xx4 xx5 xx6 ?

Comment: Yes, the number after xx is auto generated depend on the last inserted row, if the last row is xx11, the next one must be xx12

Comment: Could you use an Oracle sequence with increment by 3 and then back fill?

Comment: yes but in case an exception happened I'll rollback all records and I'l have some unused keys

Comment: Why must the sequences be sequential with no gaps?

Comment: This is one of requirements by client